# Solving a systemof eqns by given initial conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, generalized-eigenvector

I have the system

$x'(t)=2x+8y$

$y'(t)=-x-2y$

Which has the I.C. $X(0)=(6,-2)$. So I take that it means this:

$6=2x+8y$

$-2=-x-2y$

and then it is solved as any other system? We get eigenvector $(1,1/2)$, but since  the eigenvalues of the system are two, $\pm 2i$, we have to find the second generalized eigenvector.

$$ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
2-2i & 8 \\
-1 & -2-2i
\end{array} \right)
%
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1\\
\frac{1}{2}
\end{array} \right)=%
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
6-2i \\
-2-i
\end{array} \right)
$$

So the second vector would be $(6-2i, -2-i)$. Using the general solutions  for the system, we get

\begin{equation}
y(t)=e^{2it}(1, \frac{1}{2})+e^{-2it}(6-2i, -2-i)
\end{equation}

Would this be correct, or did I misinterpret the initial conditions?

Thanks

Comment: But $\left(1,\frac12\right)$ is *not* an eigenvector of $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&8\\-1&-2\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Comment: It is an eigenvector of the system below. or no

Comment: $6=2x+8y$ says $x'(0)=6$, but what you are told is $x(0)=6$. And José is correct.

Comment: so  I integrate both eqn with respect to x and y respectively, and then solve?

Comment: What is your *real* question? Is it simply how to solve that differential equation?

Comment: Yes, wiith these given initial conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If$$A=\begin{bmatrix}2&8\\-1&-2\end{bmatrix},$$then$$\exp(tA)=\begin{bmatrix}\sin (2 t)+\cos (2 t) & 4 \sin (2 t) \\ -\frac{1}{2} \sin (2 t) & \cos (2 t)-\sin (2 t)\end{bmatrix}.$$So, if $f(t)=\exp(tA).(6,-2)$, you have $f(0)=(6,-2)$ and $f'(t)=A.f(t)$. So, take\begin{align}\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)&=f(t)\\&=\bigl(6 \cos (2 t)-2 \sin (2 t),-\sin (2 t)-2 \cos (2 t)\bigr).\end{align}

Comment: Nice way of reasoning. I have completed my answer to meet your result!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't understand this. If we start at the system of equations, we prepare the matrix. Then why taking the exponent of the matrix and why do you get that the derivative of the exponent of the matrix is the matrix itself?

Comment: Because if you differentiate $e^{tA}$, what you get is $A.e^{tA}$.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the solution writes
$$
\mathbf{x}(t) = 
a_1 e^{\lambda_1 t} \mathbf{v}_1 +
a_2 e^{\lambda_2 t} \mathbf{v}_2
$$
using the eigenvector/eigenvalue of the matrix $\mathbf{A}$
in the relation
$
\dot{\mathbf{x}}(t) = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}(t)
$.

Both coefficients $a_1,a_2$ are found using the provided initial conditions
$$
\mathbf{x}(0) = 
a_1 \mathbf{v}_1 +
a_2 \mathbf{v}_2
$$
which is again a 2-by-2 linear system..

UPDATE
With Matlab commands,

```
A=[2,8;-1,-2];[U,D]=eig(A);U\[6;-2]
```

I found $a_k = 3.1820 \pm 1.0607i$ and
$\mathbf{v}_1 = [0.9428;  -0.2357 + 0.2357i]$
Thus
$$
\mathbf{x}(t) = 
a_1 e^{2i t} \mathbf{v}_1 +
a_1^* e^{-2i t} \mathbf{v}_1^* = 
2 \mathcal{R}
[
a_1 e^{2i t} \mathbf{v}_1
]
$$

UPDATE 2
Because eigenvalues/eigenvectors are complex conjugate,
it holds
$$
\mathbf{x}(0) = 
a_1 \mathbf{v}_1 +
a_1^* \mathbf{v}_1^*=
2 \mathcal{R}(a_1 \mathbf{v}_1)
$$
$$
\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}(0) = 
\lambda_1 a_1 \mathbf{v}_1 +
\lambda_2 a_2 \mathbf{v}_2 =
4i 
\mathcal{I}
(a_1 \mathbf{v}_1)
$$
Thus
$$
2 a_1 \mathbf{v}_1=
\mathbf{x}(0)-
i
\frac{\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}(0)}{2}
$$

From here simplifications occur
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mathbf{x}(t) 
&=& 
\mathcal{R}(2 a_1 \mathbf{v}_1 e^{2i t}) \\
&=&
\mathbf{x}(0) \cos(2t) +
\frac{\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}(0)}{2} \sin(2t)
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: can you specify how this includes the eigenvalues $\lambda=\pm2i$

Comment: See my update above.

Comment: Thanks for this, but since this is an exam, I wonder how one does this by hand.